# Small JavaScript charting library for streaming data

Tags: javascript, charts, streaming

Is there a small streaming data charting library that similar to [smoothiecharts](http://smoothiecharts.org/), which doesn't rely on d3.js or jQuery? The catch of smoothiecharts is that it doesn't support timeline charting.

Also, timeline chart refers to a specific type of chart that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found these projects

- [Timechart](http://timechart.toolset.io/)

I don't think it natively supports streaming, but it probably can be implemented.

- [Envision](http://www.humblesoftware.com/envision)

Looks pretty clean, and does support real-time updates.

- [Epoch](http://fastly.github.io/epoch/%20Epock)

Supports real-time graphs natively

Comment: Unfortunately, all of them don't support "timeline" charting.